# How to create new column based on average with certain conditions and ignore null in python dataframe?

Tags: python

I have 2 tables

| date | James | Jamie | John | Allysia | Jean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | NaN | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 7 | 6 | 7 | NaN | 5 |

| names | groupings |
| --- | --- |
| James | guy |
| John | guy |
| Jamie | girl |
| Allysia | girl |
| Jean | girl |

into

| date | James | Jamie | John | Allysia | Jean | girl | guy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | NaN | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 | 7 | 6 | 7 | NaN | 5 | 5.5 | 7 |

threshold= >3

I want to create a new column grouped by guys /girls scores where the score taken is above the threshold and get their mean while ignoring NaN and scores that does not fit the threshold.

I do not know on how to replace scores that is below the threshold with nan.

I tried doing to do a group by to get them in to a list and create new row with mean.

```
groupingseries = groupings.groupby(['grouping'])['names'].apply(list)
for k,s in zip(groupingseries.keys(),groupingseries):
  try:
    its='"'+',"'.join(s)+'"'
    df[k]=df[s].mean()
  except:
    print('not in item')
```

Not sure why the results return NaN for girl and guy.
Please do help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` and `groupings` your two input DataFrames:

```
out = df.join(df.groupby(df.columns.map(groupings.set_index('names')['groupings']),
                         axis=1).sum()
              )
```

Output:

```
         date  James  Jamie  John  Allysia  Jean  girl   guy
0  2022-01-01    NaN      6     5      4.0     3  13.0   5.0
1  2022-01-02    7.0      6     7      NaN     5  11.0  14.0
```